# IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to write a code for my research project. But I couldn't handle this problem although I have checked all the posts related with this. I am pretty sure that the reason is related with `numpy.array` that I use. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out where exactly it is.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

m = 1

x = np.array([1, 5, 9])
y = np.array([1, 5, 9])

def GetLJForce(r, epsilon, sigma):
    return 48 * epsilon * np.power(
        sigma, 12) / np.power(
        r, 13) - 24 * epsilon * np.power(
        sigma, 6) / np.power(r, 7)

def GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions):
    global xAcc
    global yAcc
    xAcc = np.zeros((xPositions.size, xPositions.size), dtype=object)
    yAcc = np.zeros((yPositions.size, yPositions.size), dtype=object)

    for i in range(0, xPositions.size-1):
        for j in range(i+1, xPositions.size):
            r_x = xPositions[j] - xPositions[i]
            r_y = yPositions[j] - yPositions[i]

            rmag = np.sqrt(r_x*r_x + r_y*r_y)

            force_scalar = GetLJForce(rmag, 0.84, 2.56)
            
            force_x = force_scalar * r_x / rmag
            force_y = force_scalar * r_y / rmag

            xAcc[i,j] = force_x / m
            xAcc[j,i] = - force_x / m
            
            yAcc[i,j] = force_y / m
            yAcc[j,i] = - force_y / m

    return np.sum(xAcc, axis=0), np.sum(yAcc, axis=0)

def UpdatexPos(x, v_x, a_x, dt):
    return x + v_x*dt + 0.5*a_x*dt*dt

def UpdateyPos(y, v_y, a_y, dt):
    return y + v_y*dt + 0.5*a_y*dt*dt

def UpdatexVel(v_x, a_x, a1_x, dt):
    return v_x + 0.5*(a_x + a1_x)*dt

def UpdateyVel(v_y, a_y, a1_y, dt):
    return v_y + 0.5*(a_y + a1_y)*dt

def RunMD(dt, number_of_steps, x, y):
    xPositions = np.zeros((number_of_steps, 3))
    yPositions = np.zeros((number_of_steps, 3))

    v_x = 0
    v_y = 0

    a_x = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[0]
    a_y = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[1]

    for i in range(number_of_steps):
        x = UpdatexPos(x, v_x, a_x, dt)
        y = UpdateyPos(y, v_y, a_y, dt)

        a1_x = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[0]
        a1_y = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[1]

        v_x = UpdatexVel(v_x, a_x, a1_x, dt)
        v_y = UpdateyVel(v_y, a_y, a1_y, dt)

        a_x = np.array(a1_x)
        a_y = np.array(a1_y)

        xPositions[i, :] = x
        yPositions[i, :] = y

    return xPositions, yPositions

sim_xpos = RunMD(0.1, 100, x, y)[0]
sim_ypos = RunMD(0.1, 100, x, y)[1]

np.savetxt("atomsx1.txt", sim_xpos)
np.savetxt("atomsy1.txt", sim_ypos)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "md2.py", line 80, in <module>
    sim_xpos = RunMD(0.1, 100, x, y)[0]
  File "md2.py", line 59, in RunMD
    a_x = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[0]
  File "md2.py", line 22, in GetAcc
    r_x = xPositions[j] - xPositions[i]
IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100
```

Comment: couldn't you debug this? or just put prints in the for loop?

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndexError: index 10000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316403/indexerror-index-10000-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-0-with-size-10000)

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't fix my problem although I have checked other posts which include the one that you mentioned.

Comment: When `GetAcc` is called in your code, the error occurs because `xPositions.size` is 300 (the total number of elements of `xPositions`) which is over 100. I guess you are supposed to use `xPositions.shape[0]` which is 100.

Comment: @Gorisanson , It really helped, thank you.